# finding the $n$ closest pairs between $2n$ points

Tags: st.statistics, co.combinatorics, algorithms

Given $2n$ points $x_1, x_2 \ldots x_{2n}$ and a distance $d_{i,j}$ defined between them, how can I best find the set $P$ of mutually exclusive pairs $(i,j)$ such that the sum of their distances

$$
\sum_{(i,j) \in P} d_{i,j} 
$$

is minimised? The definition of $d_{i,j}$ is open and the function could be convex. The motivation for this problem is practical. How can I pair of 30 pictures say into most similar pairs?

I apologise in advance for the choice of tags on this post. I have been out of maths proper for a long time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're looking for is a minimal weight perfect matching on a complete graph. From a quick wikipedia search, I think [Edmonds' matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27s_matching_algorithm) will do the trick for you (see the bottom of the page) - I think it's polynomial time in the number of nodes.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I think that is precisely what I need: it seems to cover the minimisation case as well as the converse maximisation. There is even some code in C++ and Python out there to do it. It also explains by my initial attempts to adapt simpler techniques failed!

Answer (score 10):

Actually, the OP is on a slightly different problem: the **Euclidean** minimal matching problem, where the complexity should be a lot better. See
[The Open Problems Project, Problem 6](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/TOPP/P6.html)
(we will probably hear more from Joseph...).
**EDIT** I also found [this paper](http://www.iam.fmph.uniba.sk/amuc/_contributed/algo2009/kolingerova.pdf)
which seems to be much simpler than Edmonds, while not being particularly 2D-oriented.

Comment: Thanks, Igor.  I will only add that there are citations under "Problem 6: Minimum Euclidean Matching in 2D" to papers that describe an exact algorithm that runs in about $O(n^{3/2})$,
and $(1 + \epsilon)$ approximation algorithms.

Comment: Oh, I should add that the original question did not specify 2D, so perhaps these references are irrelevant...

Comment: In fact, the original question seems to be in a very high-dimensional space (the space of "pictures"), so this is certainly not relevant for the OP, but should be of interest to other readers of this...

Comment: Although, see the edit.

Comment: @Igor: I'm slightly confused about "Euclidean". The OP says that the definition of $d_{ij}$ is open, so it could be non-Euclidean too?

Comment: I thought it was euclidean because he said "points", but you may well have a point...

Comment: It will most likely be Euclidean but in $R^6$ or $R^8$. However this is very much an applied problem, so if the general method works, that will be fine too. Its good to know that the other work exists: one never knows when one will need it. 